# How to prove $\phi(mn) > \phi(m)\phi(n)$ if $(m,n) \ne 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

I need to prove that

$$\phi(mn) > \phi(m)\phi(n)$$

if $m$ and $n$ have a common factor greater than 1.

I have read up on the case where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$.

Comment: Write both $m,n$ as product of power of primes, and observe that $$\varphi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1) > \varphi(p)^k = (p-1)^{k-1}(p-1)$$

Comment: J.D., this is pretty much the answer OP is looking for. You should post this.

Comment: It'd be nice to show explicitly that the natural map $U_{mn}\to U_m \times U_n$ is surjective but not injective, if it is true.

Comment: Ah, it seems that the natural map $U_{mn}\to U_m \times U_n$ has a kernel of size $d$ and an image of index $\phi(d)$ and so my idea above does not seem to work...

Comment: @Dane This is interesting.

Comment: @lhf: Your idea works well enough...it leads to Dane's answer.  (By the way, I had the same thought of expressing things in terms of this natural homomorphism.  I think it would be a positive contribution if you left this as answer.)

Answer (score 8):

According [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function/114847) recently asked question, 
$$
  \phi(mn) = \phi(m) \phi(n) \frac{d}{\phi(d)} ,
$$
where $d = \gcd(m,n)$.
Your question follows from the fact that $\varphi(d) < d$ whenever $d>1$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Write the prime factorization of both $m,n$ and observe that
$$ \varphi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1) > \varphi(p)^k = (p-1)^{k-1}(p-1).$$

I'm sorry I'm too lazy this moment to work a whole proof. But here is a simple case. If
$$ m = pq, n = ph$$
for primes $p,q,h$. Then
$$\varphi(m)\varphi(n) = \varphi(p)^2 \varphi(q)\varphi(h)$$
and $$ \varphi(mn) = \varphi(p^2)\varphi(q)\varphi(h) $$
Result follows since $\varphi(p^2) > \varphi(p)^2$ as above.