# Generalized multiplicative functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function/114847) that Euler's totient satisfies
$$
\phi(mn) = \phi(m) \phi(n) \frac{d}{\phi(d)},
$$
where $d = \gcd(m,n)$. By setting
$$
f(x)=\frac{\phi(x)}{x}
$$
this can be written as
$$
f(mn)f(d) = f(m)f(n)
$$

Have the functions that satisfy this equation been studied? They are generalized multiplicative functions.

Another generalization might be
$$
f(l)f(d) = f(m)f(n)
$$
where $l=\text{lcm}(m,n)$. The identity function satisfies this equation.

Comment: One complication is that $\frac{\phi(d)}{d}$ takes rational values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(n)=f(n)/f(1)$; then $$g(mn)g(d)=f(mn)f(d)/(f(1))^2=f(m)f(n)/(f(1))^2=g(m)g(n)$$ so $g$ has the same property and $g(1)=1$. So let's assume $f(1)=1$.

Now if $p$ is prime then $$f(p^{n+1})f(p)=f(p^n)f(p)$$ so $f(p^n)=f(p)$ for all $n\ge1$. Then $$f(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}f(p)$$ for all $n$. That is, $f$ depends only on the squarefree kernel of $n$.

I'm not sure how much there is to study about such functions.

Comment: Thanks! How about the second equation, when $f(l)f(d) = f(m)f(n)$?

Comment: The reduction to the case $f(1)=1$ still works, but you don't get any restriction on the value at prime powers. I don't know if anyone has looked at the set of functions with this property.

Comment: Ah, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function#Properties) says that *every* multiplicative function satisfies $f(l)f(d) = f(m)f(n)$. Of course. Silly me.