# Prove that $\varphi(mn)= \varphi(m,n) \cdot \varphi[m,n]$

Tags: integers

If $m$ and $n$ be positive integers Prove that $\varphi(mn)= \varphi(m,n) \cdot \varphi[m,n]$ 
where [m, n] =l.c.m of $a$ and $b$
And (m, n)=g.c.d of $a$ and $b$

My approach 
$\varphi (mn)=\varphi ((m, n) [m, n])$
$\implies ({mn/[m, n]} ,[m, n])$
$=({mn/[m, n]},{mn/(m, n)}$
Am I in right direction

Comment: If $m=n=p$, a prime, then you are claiming that $\varphi(p^2)=\varphi(p)^2$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As stated, what you want to prove is not true.

Comment: what you claim is incorrect, a possible identity is provided in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303291/eulers-totient-function-of-a-product-for-arbitrary-n-and-m

Comment: @lulu OK my approach could be wrong so I seeked help

Comment: It's not a problem with the approach.  The claim you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: @lulu OK then then please give a hint what I need to prove

Comment: I have no idea what you need to prove! The claim you want to prove isn't true. I don't see any sensible way to modify it to get a true statement (though of course I might be missing something).  Another commenter posted a link to a question with a formula in it...maybe that's something you are interested in?

Comment: @lulu the first paragraph is the question. I need to prove what is stated there

Comment: Sorry, we are going in circles.  The statement in the first paragraph is simply not true.  I gave you a counterexample.    Please study the counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not true that
$$
\varphi(mn)= \varphi(m,n) \varphi[m,n]
$$
For instance, it fails for $m=n=p$, where $p$ is prime, because $\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1) \ne p^2 = \varphi(p)^2$.

The correct identity is
$$
\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m) \varphi(n) \frac{d}{\varphi(d)}
$$
where $d = \gcd(m,n)$. See a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function-varvarphi-mn-varvarphi).

This symmetric version of that identity looks much nicer
$$
\frac{\varphi(mn)}{mn} \frac{\varphi(d)}{d} = \frac{\varphi(m)}{m} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n}
$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119659/generalized-multiplicative-functions.

Comment: Thnx for the correction I posted as it is written in the book

Comment: @John757, which book?

Comment: Classical algebra by S. K Mapa