# Show that $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof of a formula involving Euler's totient function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function)

> For positive integers $m$ and $n$ where $d=gcd(m,n)$, show that $$\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$$

This is just the generalization of the multiplicative property of *phi* function.I have tried to solve this in the same way as the proof of multiplicative property but couldn't get far.Please help.

Comment: You can find som proofs in this question (and in the questions linked to it): [Proof of a formula involving Euler's totient function.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119911/proving-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $$d=q_1^{\gamma_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot q_k^{\gamma_k}\,,\,m=d\cdot p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{\alpha_r}\,,\,n=d\cdot t_1^{\beta_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot t_s^{\beta_s}$$with $\,p_i\,,\,q_i\,,\,t_i\,$ primes , $\,\alpha_i\,,\,\beta_i\,,\,\gamma_i\in\mathbb{N}\,$ . Then, we have$$\varphi(mn)=mn\prod_{i=1}^r\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\prod_{j=1}^s\left(1-\frac{1}{t_j}\right)\prod_{l=1}^k\left(1-\frac{1}{q_l}\right)$$$$\varphi(m)=m\prod_{i=1}^r\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right)\,,\,\varphi(n)=n\prod_{j=1}^s\left(1-\frac{1}{t_j}\right)$$$$\varphi(d)=d\prod_{l=1}^k\left(1-\frac{1}{q_l}\right). $$The wanted equality follows at once.

Comment: Shouldn't this is correct $$\varphi(m)=m\prod_{i=1}^r\left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right) \prod_{l=1}^k\left(1-\frac{1}{q_l}\right)$$
same for $\varphi(n)$

Comment: Of course, @Saurabh. Thank you, I'll edit it.

Comment: @DonAntonio Have edited the answer? Please answer correctly for me.

Comment: This is not correct. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function-varphi-mn-varphi?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: This is not yet fixed. It is very confusing. But I think once you fix it based on @Saurabh, it is a simpler proof that the linked one.