# Suppose that a and b are positive integer then φ($a^b$) = a$^{b-1}$ φ(a)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove:

Suppose that a and b are positive integer then φ($a^b$) = a$^{b-1}$ φ(a)

I try many positive integer and I think it is true statement but please any help how can I start to prove it if it is true statement ?!

I know that if a is prime then φ($a^b$) =$a^b$ - $a^{b-1}$ and φ(a)=a-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $
a = \prod p_i^{e_i}
$. Then

$
\phi(a^b)
= \phi(\prod p_i^{be_i})
= \prod \phi(p_i^{be_i})
= \prod p_i^{be_i-1}(p_i-1)
= \prod p_i^{be_i} \prod \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}
= a^{b-1} a \prod \frac{p_i-1}{p_i}
= a^{b-1} \phi(a)
$

because
$$
\phi(n)= n \prod_{p \mid n} \frac{p-1}{p}
= n \prod_{p \mid n} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)
$$

Alternatively, consider $f(a) = \dfrac{\phi(a^b)}{a^{b-1}\phi(a)}$ and prove:

- $f$ is multiplicative: If $\gcd(u,v)=1$, then $f(uv)=f(u)f(v)$.
- $f(a)=1$ if $a$ is a prime power.

to conclude that $f(a)=1$ for all $a$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from

[Show that $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159397/show-that-phimn-phim-phin-fracd-phid)

For $m=n=a$ this gives $$\phi(a^2)=\phi(a)^2\cdot \frac{a}{\phi(a)}=\phi(a)a$$

Now use induction.

Comment: Thank you but I did not take any rule like $$\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\phi(n)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$$

Comment: Yes, perhaps you did not, but here on MSE it is a duplicate. The proof is easy, have a look. I do not think, any other proof for your question becomes much easier than this.