# If a prime $p \mid n$, then why does $p - 1 \mid \phi(n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I saw in the top answer for this question [Show that there is no integer n with $\phi(n)$ = 14](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754023/show-that-there-is-no-integer-n-with-phin-14) that the following assumption was made:

If a prime $p \mid n$, then $p - 1 \mid \phi(n)$, with $\phi(n)$ referring to Euler's totient function applied to $n$.

However, I am confused as to why this assumption is true.

Comment: The Euler phi function is *multiplicative*. Any decent introduction to the subject will show how a prime factorization of $n$ gives an expression for $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: See for example [Euler's totient function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p \mid n$, then $n = p^v\cdot m$ (where $p\nmid m)$. Then $$\phi(n) = \phi(p^v \cdot m) = \phi(p^v)\cdot \phi(m) = (p-1)p^{v-1}\phi(m)$$
Therefore, $p-1 \mid \phi(n)$.