# Showing an equality of Euler Totient Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, totient-function

> Show the following identity for Euler’s ϕ function:
>
> $ϕ(m · n) = \frac{ϕ(m) · ϕ(n) · gcd(m, n)}{ϕ(gcd(m, n))}$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(m) = m \prod_{p \mid m } (1-\frac{1}{p}).  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(n) = n \prod_{p \mid n } (1-\frac{1}{p}).  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(m.n) = m.n \prod_{p \mid m.n } (1-\frac{1}{p}).  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(gcd(m,n)) = gcd(m,n) \prod_{p \mid gcd(m,n) } (1-\frac{1}{p}).  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\$\frac{\phi(m).\phi(n).gcd(m,n)}{\phi(gcd(m,n))} = \frac{m \prod_{p \mid m } (1-\frac{1}{p}).n \prod_{p \mid n } (1-\frac{1}{p}).gcd(m,n)}{gcd(m,n) \prod_{p \mid gcd(m,n) } (1-\frac{1}{p})}=m.n \prod_{p \mid m.n } (1-\frac{1}{p})=\phi(m.n) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Is this correct?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754341/prove-that-if-d-gcdm-n-then-phimn-phim-phin-d

Answer (score 1):

HINT: 
Express $m$ and $n$ in terms of their prime factorisations
\begin{eqnarray*}
m= \prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{ \alpha_i} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
and use 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi(r) = r \prod_{p \mid r } (1-\frac{1}{p}).  \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I've edited my question, I tried to solve it, can you please check if it's correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
This is in fact correct, but there is a better way to do it than considering the product for the totient function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use
$$\frac{\phi(n)}{n}= \prod_{p |n } (1-\frac{1}{p})$$