# If $m, n$ be positive integers, prove that $\phi(mn)=\phi((m,n))\phi([m,n])$, where $(m,n)=$ gcd of $m, n$ and $[m, n]=$ lcm of $m, n$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **If $m, n$ be positive integers, prove that $\phi(mn)=\phi((m,n))\phi([m,n])$, where $(m,n)=$ gcd of $m, n$ and $[m, n]=$ lcm of $m, n$.**

I have no idea to solve this question. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: See also [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/114841/242)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let $d=\text{gcd}(m,n)$, it is claimed that
$$
\varphi(n)\varphi(m)=\varphi(d)\varphi(mn/d).
$$
Dividing each side by $mn$, this is equivalent to
$$
\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\prod_{p\mid m}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)=\prod_{p\mid d}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\prod_{p\mid mn}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right).
$$
This is true because each factor in the left hand side compares exactly once in the right hand: everything is collected in the last product, and the repeated terms between the first two factors appears in $\varphi(d)/d$.

Answer (score 7):

It is false. Take $m=n$.

You can prove that the statement holds if and only if we are in the trivial case $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$.

To be precise, the claim should be modified to
$$
\varphi(mn)=\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)\cdot \varphi(\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)).
$$

---

Proof:

Since $mn=\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)\mathrm{gcd}(m,n)$ and a prime $p$ divides $mn$ if and only if it divides $\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$ then
$$
\frac{\varphi(mn)}{mn}=\prod_{p\mid mn}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)=\prod_{p\mid \mathrm{lcm}(m,n)}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)=\frac{\varphi(\mathrm{lcm}(m,n))}{\mathrm{lcm}(m,n))}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\frac{\varphi(mn)}{mn}=\frac{\varphi(\mathrm{lcm}(m,n))}{mn} \cdot \mathrm{gcd}(m,n)
$$
hence the above claim..

Comment: What is the meaning of φ(rad(gcd(m,n))) ?

Comment: gcd is the greatest common divisor; lcm is the least common multiple; $\varphi$ is the Euler's phi; $rad(x)$ is the product of distinct primes dividing $x$, i.e. its radical

Comment: Then how to prove the new form of the problem?

Comment: Can it be a right question: Prove that $\phi(m)\phi(n) = \phi(gcd(m, n))\phi(lcm(m, n))$ for all $m, n \in N$

Comment: Again (6,9) is a counterexample. We are not trying to guess the correct question! If you dont know that it is the correct exercise, you should say it ....

Comment: The question given above is taken from a very std book. There is no typos when I have copied the question from that book. I don't know whether the problem given in the book is correct or wrong. But with (6,9) as a counterexample, it shows problem. If your claim that you have given above is correct, please prove that.

Comment: Give me the name of your book please, then i will add the proof

Comment: I cannot find it, but nevermind. Here is the proof

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your last result shows $$
{\varphi(mn)}={\varphi(\mathrm{lcm}(m,n))} \cdot \mathrm{gcd}(m,n)
$$
But the question is $$
{\varphi(mn)}={\varphi(\mathrm{lcm}(m,n))} \cdot \varphi(\mathrm{gcd}(m,n))
$$

Comment: I already proved you that your claim is wrong...

Comment: If you dont like the counterexample proof, and you want to claim the both statements above are true, then it should be that $\varphi(x)=x$ where $x=\text{gcd}(m,n)$. Do you agree that this is possible if and only if $x=1$?

Comment: The question that I have given is also available in the book of Burton (Q No 14b, PP 136, PROBLEMS 7.2). Please check it.

Comment: I have the fifth edition.. Can you check where is it exactly?

Comment: Burton , 5th Edition (Q No 14b, PP 134, PROBLEMS section 7.2) ϕ(m)ϕ(n)=ϕ(gcd(m,n))ϕ(lcm(m,n))

Comment: Indeed, he asks for $\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$, not $\varphi(mn)$ [recall that they are equal if and only if m and n are coprime, as expected..]

Comment: Yes, Prove that ϕ(m)ϕ(n)=ϕ(gcd(m,n))ϕ(lcm(m,n)) for all m,n∈N, I asked the same on Aprl 26, see few discussion lines above from here. .

Comment: Oh I see now that (6,9) is not a counterexample for the new problem. Wait, I put it in a new answer

Comment: It is true that the claim is false, take $m=n$, but your argument is not.

Comment: @reuns The question was different at the beginning. However, I edited it.

Comment: The first part is still not correct. The second part is correct : if $p^k | a$ then $\varphi(ap^k) = p^k \varphi(a)$. Thus $mn = \gcd(m,n) \text{lcm}(m,n)$ where $\gcd(m,n)\ |\ \text{lcm}(m,n) \implies \varphi(mn) = \gcd(m,n)\varphi(\text{lcm}(m,n))$

Answer (score 0):

This is false.

To see this, let’s start with a lemma:

$$\phi(mn) = \frac{\phi(m) \phi(n)d}{\phi(d)}.$$ where $d = (m,n).$

Proof of lemma:

$$\frac{\phi(mn)}{mn} = \prod_{p \mid mn}(1-\frac{1}{p}) = \frac{\prod_{p \mid m}(1-\frac{1}{p}) \prod_{p \mid n}(1-\frac{1}{p})}{\prod_{p \mid (m,n)}(1- \frac{1}{p})} = \frac{\frac{\phi(m)}{m} \frac{\phi(n)}{n}}{\frac{\phi(d)}{d}}$$ and we are done.

Now, if we consider any integers $a,b$ then $m = (a,b), n = [a,b]$ and so $d = (m,n) = m$ since $m \mid n$ in this case. Thus, the lemma above yields

$$ \phi(ab) = \phi((a,b)[a,b]) = \frac{\phi((a,b)) \phi([a,b]) (a,b)}{\phi((a,b))} = \phi([a,b])(a,b)$$ and so equality with what you have holds only when $$(a,b) = \phi(a,b).$$ Now, the only integer $k$ that satisfies $\phi (k) = k$ is $k = 1$ (I leave this fact to you). This tells us that $(a,b) = 1$ by necessity for equality to hold. So, the integers must be coprime.

To see an example where equality doesn’t hold, consider $a = 2, b = 6$. Then $$\phi ((2,6)) \phi ([2,6]) = \phi(2) \phi (6) = 2 \neq 4 = \phi (12) = \phi ((2,6)[2,6]).$$

Answer (score -2):

First of all, we have $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\cdot\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=ab$, then now you need to ascertain that Euler's Totient Function has the following property: $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$. Hint: write a matrix with *mn* entries.

Comment: $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$ holds only when m and n are co-prime. Then how to use this theorem here. Please write in details for me. Also how to write the matrix.