# Φ(mn) = Φ{ (m, n)Φ[m, n] } ∀ m,n ∈ ℕ

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let m and n be any two positive integers. Then prove that :  Φ(mn) = Φ{ (m, n)Φ[m, n] } where (m,n)=the g.c.d.of m and n and [m, n]= the l.c.m of m and n

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252244/if-m-n-be-positive-integers-prove-that-phimn-phim-n-phim-n-wh

Comment: $m = p, n = p^2, (m,n) = p, [m,n] = p^2$, $\phi(p^3) \ne \phi(p) \phi(p^2)$. @labbhattacharjee

Comment: Not even mentioning the case $m=n$...

Comment: The correct "duplicate" is thisone https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114841/276986