# If $\varphi(mn)=\lambda \varphi(m)\varphi(n)$ what should be written for $\lambda$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function

Respected All.

I am studying number theory where I came to know that $\varphi(n), \sigma(n)$ both are multiplicative function ; In other words, if $(m,n)=1$ then 
\begin{align}
\sigma(mn)=\sigma(m)\sigma(n),\\
\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)
\end{align}

But my question is: what if $(m,n)\neq 1$ ? In this case, how shall I relate 
$\varphi(mn), \varphi(m), \varphi(n)$ ? Is there any closed expression ? What about $\sigma(mn), \sigma(m), \sigma(n)?$ Well I know the equality will not hold, but if $\varphi(mn)=\lambda \varphi(m)\varphi(n)$ what should I write for $\lambda$ ? Same for $\sigma$.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function) and [other questions linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/114841) for the part about totient functions.

Comment: The book Sandor, Mitrinovic, Crstici: *Handbook of number theory I* contains [section called on $\sigma(mn)$](https://books.google.com/books?id=XT1-HjeXFgYC&pg=PA87). But the authors only list some inequalities in this section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)\dfrac{d}{\varphi(d)}$ where $d=\text{gcd}(m,n)$

Comment: what about $\sigma(mn), \sigma(m), \sigma(n)$ in general ?