# Prove $\phi(m)\phi(n)=\phi((m,n))\phi([m,n])$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Let $l=[m,n]$ be the lowest common multiple of $m$ and $n$ and let $d=(m,n)$ be the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$.

Prove $\phi(m)\phi(n)=\phi(l)\phi(d)$.

1. We know $mn=dl$.
2. We also know $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$.

It is clear that $(d,l)=d$. Now appliying the $\phi$ to 1. and using 2. we get,
$$\phi(mn)=\phi(dl)$$
$$\phi(m)\phi(n)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}=\phi(d)\phi(l)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}.$$
$\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$ cancels on both sides, thus the statement is proven.

Is this correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)=\varphi(\gcd(a,b))\varphi(\operatorname{lcm}[a,b])$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213945/prove-varphia-varphib-varphi-gcda-b-varphi-operatornamelcma-b) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cvarphi(m)%5Cvarphi(n)%3D%5Cvarphi(%5Cgcd(m%2Cn))%5Cvarphi(%5Coperatorname%7Blcm%7D(m%2Cn))%24&p=1).

Comment: It provides a good proof, but I am still wondering if my solution is correct.

Comment: Yes, your solution is also correct, as long as you can use the $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)\frac{d}{\phi(d)}$ result without proving it (FYI, this relation is listed in the third bullet point, and the result you're asked to prove is the fourth bullet point, in the [Other formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae) section of Wikipedia's "Euler's totient function" article).