# If $\phi(m) = \phi(mn)$ and $n \gt 1$, prove that $n = 2$ and $m$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was considering putting $\phi(mn)$ and $\phi(m)$ into their canonical form, but I'm not exactly too sure how this would help.

How would one approach this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  first show that $m,n$ must be relatively prime.

Comment: How would one go about proving that?

Comment: Suppose there was a prime $p$ dividing $\gcd(m,n)$.  Compute the order of $p$ in the unique factorization of both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already proven [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function-varphi-mn-varphi) result, you can just apply it and your result drops straight out: if $n > 2$, then $\phi(n) \geq 2$, and since $\gcd(m,n) \geq \phi(\gcd(m,n))$, we have $\phi(mn) \geq 2\phi(m) > \phi(m)$. Similarly, if $n = 2$ and $m is even$, then $\gcd(m,n) = 2$, so $\frac{\phi(m,n)}{\phi(m)} = 2\phi(n) \geq 2 > 1$.

If you haven't proven that result (and don't feel like just proving it to do this problem, we can proceed as you suggest:

$$\frac{\phi(mn)}{\phi(m)} = \frac{\displaystyle mn\prod\limits_{p|mn}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)}{\displaystyle m \prod\limits_{p|m}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)} = n\prod\limits_{\substack p|\,n\\p\not\,|\,m}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) \geq n\prod\limits_{p|n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) = \phi(n).$$

Thus, if $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)$, then $\phi(n) = 1$, so $n = 2$.

But then we have $$\frac{\phi(2m)}{2\phi(m)} = \prod\limits_{\substack p|\,2\\p\not\,|\,m}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right).$$

If $m$ is even, then that product is empty, so $\phi(2m) = 2\phi(m) \neq \phi(m)$ (since $m \neq 1$, since $1$ is not even). Thus, $m$ must be odd.

As an added bonus, we see that this condition is both necessary and sufficient: if $m$ is odd, then $\phi(2m) = \phi(2)\phi(m) = \phi(m)$, since $\phi$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this statement is true: $n\prod\limits_{\substack p|\,n\\p\not\,|\,m}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) \geq n\prod\limits_{p|n}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)$

Comment: The right hand side is just the left hand side, with (possibly) some more multiplicands added. All of those multiplicands are less than 1, so the whole term has gotten smaller (or stayed the same if $m$ and $n$ are coprime).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* This may be overkill, but it is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function/114847) that Euler's totient satisfies
$$
\phi(mn) = \phi(m) \phi(n) \frac{d}{\phi(d)},
$$
where $d = \gcd(m,n)$.

Comment: We're not told anything about the gcd or if theyre relatively prime

Comment: @Wallace, the formula works for every $m,n \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: It is not overkill, but I would add that $1=\phi(n)\cdot d/\phi(d)$ has only the solution $1=1\cdot 1$ in positive integers (this might be "underkill", of course).