# Question on the Euler phi funtion.

Tags: totient-function

Let $\phi$ be a Euler function. (i.e. $\phi(n)=$ the number of the set $\{m \in \mathbb{N} | (n,m)=1 \text{ and } 1\le m \le n \}$

When $(n,m)=1$, it is known $\phi(nm)=\phi(n)\phi(m)$.

I am wondering whether the converse is ture. I mean, if $\phi(nm)=\phi(n)\phi(m)$, then $m,n$ should be coprime? If not, is there any counterexample?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes $m$ and $n$ must be coprime. https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/higher_math_online/section03.08.html

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/proof-of-a-formula-involving-eulers-totient-function-varphi-mn-varphi)